# Can anybody color this map using the four color theorem?

Tags: geometry, cartography

I thought this was an interesting concept so I tried to make an impossible map using this.
I also tested it on a solving website and it ended up giving me 6 different colors...[A picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imt8I.png)

[The website's attempt to solve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8OEL.png)

Comment: Well, why not try to do it yourself?

Comment: On the interior row of seven, keeping the outer colors the same: : Yellow, red, yellow, red, green, red, green.

Comment: easy enough. once we number the complicated  piece $1,$   then the two squarish pieces on top $2$ and $3,$   the piece in the middle must be number $4,$  after which it is all forced.

Comment: What do you mean, "using the four color theorem"? The theorem just states/is that at most 4 colours are needed. What do you think it states/is? One could claim to be "using" it when trying a different sequence of colours when one gets stuck, but one would have to do that anyway to try to find a colouring with a given number of colours.

Comment: There's a game for this kind of challenge... :P (For example: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/map.html )

Comment: I count $7$ colors in the machine-generated coloring. At least two are in regions that have unique colors but could very easily have re-used a color without changing the colors of any other region.

Answer (score 9):

Adrien I writes "Machines are powerful but humans are apparently better!"

*Really*??  For graph coloring??

Here's the graph coloring found in 0.000435 seconds by *Mathematica*:

[image]

where the vertices represent regions and edges represent "touching" in the figure.

---

Code:

```
    g = Graph[{a \[UndirectedEdge] b, a \[UndirectedEdge] c, 
   a \[UndirectedEdge] d, a \[UndirectedEdge] e, 
   a \[UndirectedEdge] f, a \[UndirectedEdge] g, 
   a \[UndirectedEdge] h, a \[UndirectedEdge] i, a \[UndirectedEdge] j,
   b \[UndirectedEdge] c, b \[UndirectedEdge] d, 
   b \[UndirectedEdge] f, b \[UndirectedEdge] g, 
   c \[UndirectedEdge] g, c \[UndirectedEdge] h, 
   c \[UndirectedEdge] i, c \[UndirectedEdge] j,
   d \[UndirectedEdge] e, e \[UndirectedEdge] f, 
   f \[UndirectedEdge] g, g \[UndirectedEdge] h, 
   h \[UndirectedEdge] i, i \[UndirectedEdge] j}];

myColors = FindVertexColoring[g, {Red, Blue, Yellow, Green}];

gg = Annotate[g,
  VertexStyle -> Thread[VertexList[g] -> myColors]];

Graph[gg, VertexSize -> Large]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to do it. I don't know how many variations can exist.

[image]

**edit** : Reasoning for why this is the only one (up to isomorphism) :

The middle layer of three must be three distinct colors, the surrounding must be the fourth color. As we have determined four necessary colors we can without loss of generality assume the colors we have assigned {white,red,yellow,green}. What remains is to determine the inner 7 areas.

The leftmost 4 of these 7 must be in the set {yellow, green}
The rightmost 4 must be in the set {red, green}

This locks the middle one to be green. And now the remaining will become systematically determined like a double set of dominoes or a recursion if you will.

Comment: You were faster, lol ! Nice solution btw :)

Comment: I came up with the same solution, I have a feeling this is the only possible solution, because once you fix the colors of the background, white tube thing and big squares, you can only choose between two colors for the leftmost small rectangle; one of those brings to a dead end, and the other path has no choices

Comment: Mine is different, so it is not the only possible solution

Comment: @mell_o_tron Yes I also suspect so.

Comment: @AdrienI if you add the yellow to the background, yours is isomorphic. I guess you could argue that there are uncountably many colours though :))

Comment: With respect to isomorphism, yes :=) ! (not sure of my English on this comment)

Answer (score 2):

Machines are powerful, but humans are apparently better (joke) !

Here is my solution.

[image: solution]

EDIT : I think an interesting method would be to color the area that has the most neighbors and then color each area by elimination. Using the chess vocabulary, it is enough to analyze the situation with a depth of $2$, that is to say, to see what happens the next move if I put this particular color, etc...

Comment: You need the surrounding yellow or you will have 5 colors =)

Comment: Technically white light contains all the colors, therefore yellow !

Comment: lol for the white light; I wonder what algorithm did OP use, and why it failed.

Comment: Yes, I would be curious to know the name of the site and the algorithm used. This is a fairly simple coloring scheme.

Comment: @AdrienI I found this one, there's an explanation of how it works, I'll give it a read: https://www.kleemans.ch/four-color-theorem-map-solver

Comment: Thanks ! I will check this website !